# How can I create a nested dictionary that performs a computation and inserts a column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Suppose I have the following dataframe with multi-index columns.  Note that this dataframe is composed of three similarly structured sub dataframes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
         [100,90,80,70,36,45], 
         [101,78,65,88,55,78], 
         [92,77,42,79,43,32], 
         [103,98,76,54,45,65]], 
         index = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', periods=4)
)

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        (("mkf", "Open"), 
         ("mkf", "Close"), 
         ("tdf", "Open"), 
         ("tdf","Close"), 
         ("ghi","Open"), 
         ("ghi", "Close"))
)
```

And then I apply a dictionary comp to it.

```
{c:df[c] for c in df.columns.levels[0]}

{'ghi':             Open  Close
       2022-01-01    36     45
       2022-01-02    55     78
       2022-01-03    43     32
       2022-01-04    45     65,
 'mkf':             Open  Close
       2022-01-01   100     90
       2022-01-02   101     78
       2022-01-03    92     77
       2022-01-04   103     98,
 'tdf':             Open  Close
       2022-01-01    80     70
       2022-01-02    65     88
       2022-01-03    42     79
       2022-01-04    76     54}
```

How can I modify the dictionary comprehension `{c:df[c] for c in df.columns.levels[0]}`
to be a nested dictionary comprehension that applies the below function to each component of the dictionary?

```
def log_return(df):
   df['r'] = np.log(df['Close']).diff()
```

Comment: are you looking for `df[c].assign(log_ret=np.log(df[c,'Close']).diff())` instead of `df[c]`?

Comment: @Neither 'd' should be 'Close'.  thanks for identifying.

Comment: Okay is `{c:df[c].assign(r=np.log(df[(c, 'Close')]).diff()) for c in df.columns.levels[0]}` good?

Comment: @Neither I think so.  Must one use `assign` when creating a new column? thank you.

Comment: That's an option for on the fly operations (otherwise you need `frame["r"] = ...` but that's an assignment and not allowed in a comprehension). Another option would be concatenation, i.e., `pd.concat([df[c], np.log(df[(c, 'Close')]).diff().rename("r")], axis=1)` but this is less readable I guess.

Comment: @Neither this article suggests that you can use assignments in a comprehension.  Might try this.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-assignment-expressions-in-python

Comment: Yes that's an assignment *expression* for Python 3.8+ but I think your case is complicated  enough to not use that. But good luck!